# HTML5 Canvas fillStyle as numbers not text

Tags: html5, html-canvas, browser-based-games

When drawing vector graphics in the canvas you set the fillStyle using an rgba string like this...

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 223, 191, 1)";
```

Is it possible to feed in a javascript object instead (or just numbers). Seems silly that I would need to construct a string to feed to this value if I wanted the color dynamic.

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 223, 191, " + alpha + ")";
```

The specification clearly says "a CSS Color string" but it seems crazy. Am I missing something?

http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#fill-and-stroke-styles

update: I switched to using globalAlpha for this specific example. But still seems crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you're not missing anything. This has to be a string, containing [a valid CSS color value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#color-units).

To reassure you, [you're not the first one wondering why so much hate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957346/programatically-use-rgba-values-in-fillstyle-in-canvas).